# What are the reasons which make intron detection uncertain?

Tags: dna, rna, polymerase, exons, introns

Intron/exon sequence detection seems to involve statistical prediction which can at best deliver a guess (until experimentally confirmed) as to where the splice site is.

What are the reasons why there are no deterministic (rather than consensus) sequences which signal the location splice sites?

Trying to answer this myself, I guess the obvious one I can see is chromatin structure, which interacts with how RNA polymerase reads the DNA strand.  If this is the case however, isn't the current way of describing DNA as a sequence of AGCT base pairs fundamentally flawed?  If chromatin structure is actually part of the functional description of DNA, then are there any efforts being made to describe this?